# Modify an operator in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, operators

I currently use two different fragments to show half a List :

Fragment 1

```
if (i%2 != 1) {
Show first half List;
}
```

Fragment 2

```
if (i%2 == 1) {
Show second half List;
}
```

But I would like something cleaner with one fragment called twice :

Fragment

```
prefOperator = bundle.getInt(WHICH_HALF);
if (prefOperator == 1) OPERATOR = "!=";
else if (prefOperator == 2) OPERATOR = "==";

if (i%2 OPERATOR 1) {
Show List;
}
```

I guess this is possible but can't find how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of changing operator, change the value you're comparing to:

```
// Since WHICH_HALF has value 1 or 2, we will subtract one.
int prefOperator = bundle.getInt(WHICH_HALF) - 1;

if (i%2 == prefOperator) {
  // Show first half of list
} else {
  // Show second half of list
}
```

Comment: I was about to send the same solution

Comment: Thanks ! I should have thought about it !